# Change the tabBar style in react-native using ex navigation

Tags: react-native

I am using ex-navigation for navigating inside my app. Everything works fine, except I want to change the white color line that's above the tabBar.

[image]

```
export default class TabEntry extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationProvider router={Router}>
                <TabNavigation id="main" navigatorUID="main" initialTab="home"
                               tabBarColor="#22313F" tabBarHeight={48}>

                    <TabNavigationItem id="notification">
                        <StackNavigation id="notification" navigatorUID="notification" initialRoute={Router.getRoute('notification')}/>
                    </TabNavigationItem>

                    <TabNavigationItem id="home">
                        <StackNavigation id="home" navigatorUID="home" initialRoute={Router.getRoute('home')}/>
                    </TabNavigationItem>

                </TabNavigation>
            </NavigationProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the style of the tabBar by applying borderWidth and BorderColor like the below but it didn't help me:

```
<TabNavigation id="main" navigatorUID="main" initialTab="home"
               tabBarColor="#22313F" tabBarHeight={48}
               tabBarStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red'}}>
```

Am I missing somethig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is be more specific with your `borderColor`:

```
<TabNavigation 
  id="main" 
  navigatorUID="main" 
  initialTab="home"         
  tabBarColor="#22313F" tabBarHeight={48}
  tabBarStyle={{
    borderWidth: 1, 
    borderTopColor: 'red'    // Just change this to `borderTopColor`
  }}>
```

And that should do it! [Docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style)

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thank you.